# Add multiple arrays in single table

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

```
<table border="2">
<?php 
foreach($array1 as $value)
{
    echo '<tr><td>';
    echo $value;
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

I have more array: array2,array3.
The above code only executes values of array1 but I want all the values of all array in the same table in separate columns!

```
array1 | array2 | array3
------------------------
       |        |
       |        |
       |        |
       |        |
```

I want something like this... 
I tried modifying the code but no idea how to do it correctly.

```
$data = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM user_pokemon_db WHERE user_id = '".$id."' "); 
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) { 
    $db_id = $rows['id']; 
    $array[] = $db_id; 
    $level = $rows['level']; 
    $array1[] = $level; 
    $exp = $rows['exp']; 
    $array2[] = $exp; 
    $pkmn_id = $rows['pkmn_id']; 
    $data1 = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM pokemons WHERE pk_id = '".$pkmn_id."' "); 
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($data1)) { 
        $poke = $rows['path']; $array3[] = $poke; 
    } 
}
```

The above code fetches data from database and adds it to different arrays!

Comment: Can you display the content of these arrays? have they the same structure? shared keys?

Comment: why do you have <tr> inside a <td> ?

Comment: No, I have corrected it in my code.. just I missed that to edit before posting. Ill do it now.

Comment: Have you tried combining your queries to one query? This way you can gel all the data in one go and inset it into one multidimensional array.

Comment: One idea could be, not using foreach but using simple for loop considering the array having largest size, and then print them, so that there won't be 'undefined offset' error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your array, you don't specify keys, so they are generated automaticaly. So you can work on keys for your for loop instead of using a foreach in values:

We can see in your code that $array3 is longuer than the others. So we will base on it:

```
foreach($array3 as $key => $value)
{
    if (isset($array1[$key])){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$array1[$key].'</td>';
    }else{
        echo '<tr><td></td>';
    }
    if (isset($array2[$key])){
        echo '<td>'.$array2[$key].'</td>';
    }else{
        echo '<td></td>';
    }
    echo '<td>'.$array3[$key].'</td></tr>';    
}
```

It should work

Comment: Well! It helped :) It would just need some formatting, but I ll do it Thnks alot!

Answer (score 1):

try making a function that calls itself in the end. not sure if I got the syntax right here, but this should work.

```
$i = 0;
function test($i){
    if($i < ar1.lenght && $i < ar2.lenght && $i< ar3.lenght){
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo ar1[$i];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo ar2[$i];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo ar3[$i];
        echo "</td></tr>";
        $i++;
        //calls itself with an incremented $i
        test($i);
    }//else do nothing.
}
```

--edit forgot some  tags